# Marshalling `byte[]` from .NET to `const u8*` in C

Tags: c#, c, marshalling

I have this C function:

```
void ECRYPT_keysetup(ECRYPT_ctx* ctx, const u8* key, u32 keysize, u32 ivsize);
```

that loads some key bytes to cipher context for example:

```
{0x01,0x23,0x45,0x67,0x89,0xab,0xcd,0xef,0x12,0x34,0x56,0x78,0x9a,0xbc,0xde,0xf0}
```

I want to pass `byte[]` from my .NET application to `ECRYPT_keysetup`. 
The problem is to marshall `const u8*`. Any suggestions?

`ECRYPT_ctx` is a structure:

```
u32 lfsr[1036];
u32 nfsr[1036];
u32 * nptr;
u32 * lptr;
u32 count;
const u8 * key;
u32 keysize;
u32 ivsize;
```

I have it's .NET representation:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1036)]
public UInt32[] lfsr;

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1036)]
public UInt32[] nfsr;

public UIntPtr nptr;
public UIntPtr lptr;

public UInt32 count;

public byte[] key;

public UInt32 keysize;
public UInt32 ivsize;
```

May be my mistake is in structure declaration?

Comment: If you have the source code of C encryption, you may translate it in C# instead of marshaling, etc.

Comment: How do you think @i486, what type of code will be faster? Native C, invoked from C#, or code translated to C#. Performance is very critical for me. I have to invoke functions tousands times

Comment: C will be faster but however it depends on algorithm. If it is simple like XTEA, there will be small difference.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

Map your types and use `MarshalAs` attribute:

```
[DllImport("Mylib.dll")]
private static extern void ECRYPT_keysetup(
    [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] ref ECRYPT_ctx ctx,
    [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2)]byte[] key,
    uint keysize,
    uint ivsize);

// define whatever you have here (you can use Sequential layout without offsets, too)
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
private struct ECRYPT_ctx
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal int someInt32;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
    internal byte[] someBytes;
}
```

**Solution 2**

Use pointers and marshal everything manually:

```
[DllImport("Mylib.dll")]
private static extern void ECRYPT_keysetup(IntPtr ctx, IntPtr key, uint keysize, uint ivsize);
```

In this case you should manage the allocations and disposal manually:

```
byte[] key = new byte[128]; // use the size you need, of course
IntPtr keyPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(key.Length);
Marshal.Copy(key, 0, keyPtr, key.Length);

ECRYPT_ctx ctx = new ECRYPT_ctx();
IntPtr ctxPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ECRYPT_ctx)));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(ctx, ctxPtr, false);

ECRYPT_keysetup(ctxPtr, keyPtr, (uint)key.Length, ivsize);

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(keyPtr);
Marshal.DestroyStructure(ctxPtr, typeof(ECRYPT_ctx));
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ctxPtr);
```

**Remark:** I considered all parameters as input ones. If you get something  back in the buffers, define them as `[In, Out]`, and in *Solution 2* use the `Marshal.PtrToStructure` method to convert the pointer to a managed structure.

Comment: Got `MarshalDirectiveException` to reference parameter `ECRYPT_ctx`. Tried Solution 1 @taffer.

Comment: If you gen an error message like this: `Additional information: Cannot marshal 'parameter #1': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination`, then it means that your managed and unmanaged version of `ECRYPT_ctx` do not match. I suspect that `ECRYPT_ctx.key` has a problem. You have a not fixed managed pointer there, which you cannot pass to an unmanaged API (the GC can relocate the key bytes any time). Try to switch to `IntPtr` from `byte[]` and allocate the key bytes similarly to *Solution 2*.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] Byte[] key`.

Comment: Unfortunately no... I tried this... Got `System.AccessViolationException`